# How to make your own online video player

Tags: video

How i can make my own online video player like YouTube has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look into the source code of [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/). You can also use Flash instead for lesser browsers (which VideoJS has a fallback for).

Or, you could simply use VideoJS (there is even a YouTube skin for it). :)

Answer (score 2):

An online video player can be developed easily using [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) or [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/). However, if you are targeting newer browsers, I'd suggest you use the HTML5 video tag. Link [here](http://html5video.org/) and explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp). Youtube has also beta'd HTML5 video at `http://www.youtube.com/html5`.

Good luck!